# Python численное дифференцирование сложных функций

Tags: python

Нужно запрограммировать численное дифференцирование сложных функций в Python. Что нужно использовать?А лучше наглядный пример программы.

Comment: Приведите пример входной функции и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе

Comment: входная функция - кубический корень (x**2+tan(x)+15)                                           
ответ - 1/(3*(x**2+tan(x)+15)**2/3) * (2*x+1/cos(x)**2)

Comment: т.е. вам все-таки нужно аналитическое, а не численное решение?

Comment: как аналитически решить - я понимаю.мне бы программу составить.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/ru/). Он довольно неплохо умеет считать производные:

```
from sympy import *
expr = diff("x**2+sin(cos(x))")
# expr: 2*x - sin(x)*cos(cos(x))
```

Можно и вычислить в какой-нибудь точке:

```
print( expr.evalf(subs={'x':2}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
In [74]: from sympy import *

In [75]: x = symbols('x')

In [76]: diff('(x**2+tan(x)+15)**(1/3)')
Out[76]: (2*x/3 + tan(x)**2/3 + 1/3)/(x**2 + tan(x) + 15)**(2/3)
```